# How to pass string in URL as parameter to new URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We need to redirect an old URL structure that is sill beeing communicated to clients to a new format. The source URL looks like this:

https://example.com/de/home/empfangengibq824ua1

the key that needs to be processed follows after "empfangen", so: gibq824ua1
(i dont know who came up with this)

these requests need to be redirected to (same domain):
https://example.com/empfangen?zustellungnr=gibq824ua1

Any idea how to accomplish this with an .htaccess redirect?

Thanks!

Comment: flagged as "not useful" and "no research effort"?  i've researched and tried quiet a bit, also discussing it with our IT department and hosting company.

Answer (score 1):

RewriteRule "^/de/home/empfangen/(.*)$" "/empfangen?zustellungnr=$1"